# How to navigate to indendation levels in vim

Tags: vim

I have the following code (line numbers included):

```
1 def test():
2     a = 1
3     b = 1
4     c = 1
5     d = 1
6     if a == 1:
7          print('This is a sample program.')
```

And the cursor is on line 7, the last line. Is there a fast, and ideally one key, way to navigate up to line 6, which is one indentation level up, and then, on the next key press, to line 1, one indentation level up again? Conversely, is there a matching method to "drill down" that way?

Comment: See https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14115

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a plugin for that: https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/vim-indentwise

The mappings it provides that match what you are looking for are:

- [- : Move to previous line of lesser indent than the current line.
- [+ : Move to previous line of greater indent than the current line.
- ]- : Move to next line of lesser indent than the current line.
- ]+ : Move to next line of greater indent than the current line.

Then, if you really wanted to do what you asked for in a single keypress, you can remap them like so, for example:

```
nmap - [-
nmap + ]+
```